# Formatting Timestamp in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataset representing an electrical signal (as an array) that need's to be passed as a pandas dataframe to another function.  The thing is the dataframe has to have an index with a freq attribute, and the original dataset doesn't have a timestamp, 1d array with the samples, but I know the sample freq (86Hz) so I can assign a timestamp for each sample:

```
>>>a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>>b = []
>>>j=0
>>>for i in a:
>>>    b.append(round(j, 3))
>>>    j = j+(1/86)
>>>c = np.c_[b, a]
     ([[ 0.   ,  1.   ],
       [ 0.012,  2.   ],
       [ 0.023,  3.   ],
       [ 0.035,  4.   ],
       [ 0.047,  5.   ],
       [ 0.058,  6.   ]])
```

Then I turn it in to a dataframe:

```
d = pd.DataFrame(data=c[0:,1], index=c[0:,0])

        0
0.000   1.0
0.012   2.0
0.023   3.0
0.035   4.0
0.047   5.0
0.058   6.0
```

The problem is the index has no freq attribute, I think it's a formatting issue, but not sure, and after a loot of googling I didn't find anything.

When I write:

```
d.index.freq
```

it should return 86, but gives me an:

> AttributeError: 'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'freq'

By the way, the timestamp is in seconds, starting with the first sample... or that is my intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do it like this:

```
In [109]: d.index = pd.timedelta_range(d.index.min(), periods=len(d), freq='86L')

In [110]: d
Out[110]:
                   0
00:00:00         1.0
00:00:00.086000  2.0
00:00:00.172000  3.0
00:00:00.258000  4.0
00:00:00.344000  5.0
00:00:00.430000  6.0

In [111]: d.index.freq
Out[111]: <86 * Millis>

In [112]: d.index.dtype
Out[112]: dtype('<m8[ns]')

In [113]: d.index.dtype_str
Out[113]: 'timedelta64[ns]'
```

Comment: @Danf, glad it helps :)